# Can jmeter send request more expected samples?

Tags: jmeter

-I has a request for post data to server.

-I config Jmeter with info :

- Number of Threads(users) : 16
- Ramp-up : 1 and check forever
- I run jmeter about 15 minutes(900s) and stop.After,i view report and see report display about 45000 samples .
- => I think only 14400 samples expect for 15 minutes but display more samples.
  So,Can jmeter run more samples (> 16 thread in 1s) although i config 16 threads in 1s ?
- Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

JMeter tries to execute samplers **as fast as it can**, each thread sends request, waits for response, sends another request, etc.

You will get 14400 samplers only if response time for each sampler will be exactly **equal to 1 second**. If response time is less than one second - you will get more samplers executed within the given timeframe and vice versa.

If you need to throttle JMeter execution rate to 960 requests per minute (16 requests per second) you can use one of the following elements:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Be aware that both timers are capable of only **pausing** JMeter threads to limit the load to the defined factor, they won't be able to kick off any extra threads to reach the target throughput in case if current is too low.

Comment: Thanks for your support !